# Android AWS S3 SDK 2.2.16 TransferListener receiving incorrect onProgressChanged Data

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

The issue is with AWS S3 upload process, when I try to upload a file sometimes I am receiving more bytesCurrent than bytesTotal which is making the progress calculation to go more than 100%. But when I checked the size of photo on device, S3 storage and the logs which show bytesTotal for that file all of them to be same. Have someone else seen this issue with onProgressChanged. Please let me know.

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
    // Calculate percentage here.
    Log.d("Upload Status", "file id: " + id + ", bytesCurrent: " + bytesCurrent + ", bytesTotal: " + bytesTotal);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug, but it's fixed in v2.2.19. See [release notes](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/Android/2688202614988726). Please upgrade the SDK.